# Ptr Word8 to [Word8]

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I'm using the library `Network.Pcap`, and it has the function `toBS`

```
toBS :: (PktHdr, Ptr Word8) -> IO (PktHdr, B.ByteString)
toBS (hdr, ptr) = do
    let len = hdrCaptureLength hdr
    s <- B.create (fromIntegral len) $ \p -> B.memcpy p ptr (fromIntegral len)
    return (hdr, s)
```

Right now I am unpacking the ByteString which gives me the `[Word8]` I want. I'
m looking for a way to avoid having to unpack the `ByteString`, and get the `[Word8]` directly.

(1) Does this function exist?
(2) If not, could I get some advice on how to proceed?

Comment: In the end, do you want some function `g :: IO (PktHdr, B.ByteString) -> IO (PktHdr, [Word8])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with those libraries, but can't you just do this?

```
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

toByteList :: PktHdr -> Ptr Word8 -> IO [Word8]
toByteList hdr ptr = peekArray (fromIntegral (hdrCaptureLength hdr)) ptr
```